# cakePHP ACL when not logged in

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an application where all users have to be logged in. I'm using the `Auth` component for authentication, and `ACL` for authorization.

I'm basically doing something like this in the `beforeFilter() of an admin controller:

```
if(!$this->Acl->check(array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => $this->Auth->user()['id']), 'Admin', 'read')) 
{
    pr('You are NOT allowed to be here!');
}
```

This works well for any logged in user, some users can see the admin pages, and some cannot.

However, when I go to */admin* when NOT logged in, I get:

> AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by
>   "Array ( [Aro0.model] => model [Aro0.foreign_key] => U )
>   "

(I don't know why it prints the 'U'). It's like it's trying to do the lookup, but since the user information isn't there, it crashes. I'm sure I'm missing something here. I can avoid the problem by checking if the user is logged in:

```
if($this->Auth->user()) //do the ACL check
```

But I don't like that approach, and I guess it is wrong.

Do I need some kind of default setting?

Answer (score 0):

That error means that in your Database you don't have the node in acos.
Also the foreign_key of the relationship is wrong! Maybe you should check [Cake Book - Simple Acl controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) and afterwards I will give you more details on what you don't understand.

In beforeFilter() you should have only the Guest allows, the rest of the privileges are in the DB.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm new to ACL stuff, and the documentation is messy. I don't understand why I don't have it in acos, since it does work when I am a logged in user. Also, why is the foreign_key wrong? It points to the logged in user.